# Pass Botium Scripting Memory Variables into Asserter

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here's a sample *test.convo.text*:

```
Test asserter

#me
Show my json

#bot
$json

MY-CUSTOM-ASSERTER $json
```

The asserter picks up '$json' string as the args.

I wanted the JSON replied by the bot to be passed as args.

Is there a way to access Scripting Variables like how we access `process.env`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing an asserter, one of the parameters handed over to the asserter function is "botMsg" which actually contains the chatbot response (in botMsg.messageText) - so I don't see any sense in doing it with this $json scripting variable. You can find detailed list of arguments for the custom asserters in the [Botium Wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/24477705/Developing+Custom+Asserters).

Your custom asserter could look like this:

```
module.exports = class CustomAsserter {
  assertConvoStep ({args, scriptingMemory, botMsg}) {
    // do whatever you want with botMsg and scriptingMemory
    if (botMsg.messageText !== 'HUGO') return Promise.reject('Expected HUGO')
    return Promise.resolve()
  }
}
```

You can access environment variables as scripting variables with $func

```
#me
add to my cart $func(process.env.BOTIUM_PRODUCT)
```